# Use of Repeat loop for Saving CSV file

Tags: r

I am reading each worksheet of Excel File named "REL" up to worksheet 4 using the `repeat` function given below. But after reading worksheet for each value of `i`, I want to save it first in my working directory before reading for `i + 1`.

```
i <- 1
repeat {
  fcr <- read.xlsx("REL.xlsx", sheet = i, colNames = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  print(i)
  if (i > 4) {
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `write.csv(fcr, file=paste0("fcr",i,".csv", sep=""), col.names=FALSE)` before the second condition "if (i > 4)".

Comment: A) Create an emply list outside the loop. B) Assign the result of the read operation to `fcr[[i]]`. Then you can do anything you want with the results.

Answer (score 2):

In the future please indicate which packages you are using when referencing non-base functions; presumably this is `read.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package. To save each worksheet as a csv, you would need to call `write.csv(...)` after reading the file in, and before the loop begins its next iteration. But you shouldn't even bother with `repeat`, etc... as above. Use something more idiomatic to R such as `sapply`:

```
library(xlsx)
##
list.files()
#[1] "REL.xlsx"
##
sapply(1:4, function(i) {
  write.csv(
    read.xlsx("REL.xlsx", sheetIndex = i, header = TRUE),
    file = sprintf("WS%d.csv", i)
  )
})
##
list.files()
#[1] "REL.xlsx" "WS1.csv"  "WS2.csv"  "WS3.csv"  "WS4.csv"
```